# Silverlight 2 How to know all ASYNC WCF calls has been completed

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous

Tools : SilverLight 2, C# 3.5, VS2008 and WCF
Async Programming

In my SL2 application, I am making 3 async wcf calls as follows -

```
void HomeScreen()
{

//Async WCF Calls
DataService.GetPersonInfo(sUser);
DataService.GetSalaryInfo(sUser);
DataService.GetDepartmentInfo(sUser);

//Where to put this code?
//Page.Redirect("MainScreen");

}
```

After all 3 async calls has been completed i need to move user to a MainScreen.
How do i know that all 3 async calls has been completed ?

> (without using loop to check global
>   variable for async method status)

Does SL2 has any inbuilt feature like Jquery to know all async call has been completed 
for ex -

```
$().ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Any Thoughts ?

Comment: I don't think there's a built in call like the Jquery you wrote; you'll have to choose a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

```
DataService.GetPersonInfo(sUser, (result) => 
 {
    DataService.GetSalaryInfo(sUser, 
       (result) => 
       {
         DataService.GetDepartmentInfo(sUser, (result) =>
           {
                 Page.Redirect("MainScreen");
           }
         ); 
       } 
    );
 }
);
```

But your GetPersonInfo method will have to change it like

```
GetPersonInfo(user, Action<bool> complete){
   //And call complete.Invoke(true); or false based on completing of the processs.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: oh. Rich Text Editor here remove \n :(

Answer (score 2):

Similiar to Jacob, abstract this away into a separate class.  This will at least simplify your calling class and remove the complexity of joining the calls.

In your class, in the simplest terms simply on each completed event from the async call, check how many events have completed, if it matches the total, fire a completed event of your own.  Somethign like this:

```
public class DataProvider()
{
  private int callCount = 0;

  public event EventHandler Completed;
  public void Go()
  { 
    callCount = 0;
    //Async WCF Calls
    DataService.GetPersonInfo(sUser);
    DataService.GetSalaryInfo(sUser);
    DataService.GetDepartmentInfo(sUser);
  }

  public void GetSalaryInfoCompleted(object sender, SomeArgs e)
  {
    //Do something with the results here
     CheckIfCompleted();
  }
  public void GetDepartmentInfoCompleted(object sender, SomeArgs e)
  {
    //Do something with the results here
     CheckIfCompleted();
  }

  public void GetPersonInfoCompleted(object sender, SomeArgs e)
  {
     //Do something with the results here
     CheckIfCompleted();
  }

  private void CheckIfCompleted()
  {
     callCount++;
     if ( callCount == 3 )
     {
       Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: I used this to implement waiting for both an async service call and an animation to finish. Both event handlers call the method that checks to see if they're both done before triggering the next event. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that theses calls can't be made again while you're waiting, you could just add a Completed handler for each of the services. In each handler, you could set a flag for that call and them check to see if all three flags have been set. If so, then go to the main screen.